# pyqt4 drag and drop files in Qlistview

Tags: python, python-2.7, drag-and-drop, pyqt4

i can not find drag and drop the files in qlistview.

i find sample code.

but this is qlistwidget and qpushbutton

also this sample is using class

i want to make drag and drop below example.

Why can not use the dropped in qlistview?

main.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from test import *
import sys

class main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        global app
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myapp=main()
myapp.show()
app.exec_()
```

test.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(273, 214)
        self.listView = QtGui.QListView(Form)
        self.listView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 256, 192))
        self.listView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listView"))
        self.listView.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.listView.dropped.connect(mydragdrop)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))

def mydragdrop(self):
    None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class DragAndDrop(QListView):          
    def __init__(self, parent):
        global listView
        super(DragAndDrop, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Plain)
        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.Box)
        listView=self

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.acceptProposedAction()
        else:
            super(DragAndDrop, self).dragEnterEvent(event)

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(DragAndDrop, self).dragMoveEvent(event)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        #global itemModel
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                if url.path()[-5:]==".pcap":
                    if itemModel.findItems(url.path()[1:].replace("/","\\")):
                        pass
                    else:
                        item=QStandardItem(url.path()[1:].replace("/","\\"))
                        item.setCheckable(True)
                        itemModel.appendRow(item)
                else:
                    pass
            event.acceptProposedAction()
            self.setModel(itemModel)
        else:
            super(DragAndDrop,self).dropEvent(event)
```

And in my example.

```
self.verticalLayout.addWidget(listView)
```